# Is there a event fired if the sreensize is changed below a set px (mobil, tablet, desktop)

Tags: css, asp.net, media-queries, blazor, breakpoints

is there a easy way to figure out what sreensize is used by the user in Blazor (I use Blazor serverside). My app shall show differend Userinterfaces according to the screensize.
If screen width is smaller then 768px then show UI (360x640)
If screen width is smaller then 1920px then show UI (768x1024)
else use 1920x1080.

Blazor has bootstrap onboard there a predefind breakpoints for the columes rows etc.
But how can I call a c# methode the moment a breakpoint is hit?

How could I do such thing ?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

You properly need to hook into the window [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) of the browser. If you do not like to do this yourself you can have a look at this [library](https://github.com/RemiBou/BrowserInterop) which provides a lot of great wrappers.
More specifically [this event](https://github.com/RemiBou/BrowserInterop/blob/master/src/BrowserInterop/WindowInterop.cs#L833) is what you need. Then you can simply wired an event up to call your specific method when a resize occurs.
Have a look in the [SampleApp](https://github.com/RemiBou/BrowserInterop/tree/master/sample/SampleApp) provided in the repository.